# How do I find the coordinates of the point of intersection of 2 lines inside a rectangular area?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher gave me this question in a pre-test and I have no idea how to solve it. I don't know where to start and what to do. I searched online for something similar to help me but I found nothing useful.

I really want to understand so please don't give me the final answer. Just the steps to achieve it, would be great.

Thanks in advance

Here it is:
[Math problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgsTu.png)

PS: Let me know if something's not clear, I had to translate it from french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some skills you need:

- Given two points on a line, find an equation for that line (apply this to $AB$)
- Given a point on a line, and the slope of a line, find the equation of the line. (apply this to point $G$ and the line $AB$, which is parallel to the solid line through $G$.)
- Apply that again to the point $H$ and the slope of $AB$ to find the equation of the dotted line through $H$.
- Given a line of slope $m$ through a point $P$, find the equation of the line through $P$ that's perpendicular. (Apply this to the point $G$ and the slope of the line $CD$ to find the equation of the dotted line throuhg $G$)
- Given the equations of two lines, find their point of intersection. (Apply to dotted line through $G$ and the line $AB$ to find that top point, and to the two dotted lines through $F$ to find the location of $F$.

Comment: Thank you very much!